# Powershell/Forms - how to anchor listview within a tab control?

Tags: winforms, powershell, tabs, anchorpoint

I'm trying to anchor a listview within a tab page in Forms, such that the listview resizes along with the tab and the other controls are also anchored to allow this, but it looks like it's anchoring to the parent form, not the tab - example code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
#
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.MinimumSize = '585,700'
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$form.MaximizeBox = $false
$form.CancelButton = $ExitButton
#Autoscaling settings
$form.AutoScale = $true
$form.AutoScaleMode = "Font"
$ASsize = New-Object System.Drawing.SizeF(7,15)
$form.AutoScaleDimensions = $ASsize
#
#
$MainTab = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabControl
$MainTab.Size = '540,465'
$MainTab.Location = '15,95'
$MainTab.Multiline = $True
$MainTab.Name = 'TabPage'
$MainTab.SelectedIndex = 0
$MainTab.Anchor = 'Top,Left,Bottom,Right'
#
$TabPage1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
$Tabpage1.Name = 'TabPage1'
$Tabpage1.Padding = '5,5,5,5'
$Tabpage1.TabIndex = 1
$Tabpage1.Text = 'Host SSH'
$Tabpage1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$TabPage1.Enabled = $false
#
$ESXhostList = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
$ESXhostList.View = [System.Windows.Forms.View]::Details
$ESXhostList.Location = '10,15'
$ESXhostList.Size = '510,150'
$ESXhostList.Columns.Add('Host Name',420) | Out-Null
$ESXhostList.Columns.Add('SSH Status',80) | Out-Null
$ESXhostList.Anchor = 'Top,Left,Right'
#
$ConnectBtn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ConnectBtn.Location = '20,190'
$ConnectBtn.Size = '54,24'
$ConnectBtn.Text = 'Connect'
$ConnectBtn.BackgroundImageLayout = 'Center'
$ConnectBtn.Enabled = $true
$ConnectBtn.Anchor = 'Left,Bottom'
#
$TabPage1.Controls.AddRange(@($ESXhostList,$ConnectBtn))
################################################################################
# TabPage 2
################################################################################
$TabPage2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
$Tabpage2.Name = 'TabPage2'
$Tabpage2.Padding = '5,5,5,5'
$Tabpage2.TabIndex = 2
$Tabpage2.Text = 'Datastores'
$Tabpage2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$TabPage2.Enabled = $false
#
$DSList = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
$DSList.View = [System.Windows.Forms.View]::Details
$DSList.Location ='10,15'
$DSList.Size = '510,150'
$DSList.Columns.Add('Name',160) | Out-Null
$DSList.Columns.Add('FreeGB',65) | Out-Null
#
$ConnectBtn2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ConnectBtn2.Location = '20,190'
$ConnectBtn2.Size = '54,24'
$ConnectBtn2.Text = 'Connect'
$ConnectBtn2.BackgroundImageLayout = 'Center'
$ConnectBtn2.Enabled = $true
#
$TabPage2.Controls.AddRange(@($DSList,$ConnectBtn2))
#
#
$MainTab.Controls.AddRange(@($TabPage1,$TabPage2))
#
# Info/Logging Window
$ProgressLog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$ProgressLog.Location = '15,570'
$ProgressLog.Size = '540,80'
$ProgressLog.Multiline = $true
$ProgressLog.Anchor = 'Left,Bottom,Right'
$ProgressLog.TabStop = $false
$ProgressLog.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
$ProgressLog.ReadOnly = $true
#
# Add all the Form controls
$form.Controls.AddRange(@($MainTab,$ProgressLog))
#
#End
# Show form
$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$form.Dispose()
```

In the above example, the only difference between the tabs is that I'm trying to anchor the listview and button controls in the first tab but there's no anchoring in the second tab.

Here's Tab 1 - the listview is outside the bounds of the tab instead of being anchored within it and the button is completely off the tab area

[image: Incorrect anchoring]

Here's the identical Tab 2 with no anchoring. Correct layout but no anchoring therefore resizing form does not resize the listview or reposition the button:

[image: Correct layout but no anchoring therefore resizing form not working]

Can anyone explain how to do this, as everything I read says that anchoring the tab then anchoring controls within it should work?

Comment: You don't have anchor statements on your second tab or controls and your second tab's Name property is the same as the first.  Adding anchor statements to your second tab and correcting the name make your second tab act like the first tab for me.  They still dont' look right necessarily but it's behaving the way you asked.  ;)

Comment: I didn't put anchors on the second tab to illustrate the difference between adding them and not. The name is irrelevant to the anchoring but I've amended the typo.
Added images to illustrate

Comment: Sorry dude, I misunderstood yoru question:  $DSList.AutoSize = [System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode]::GrowAndShrink

Comment: That doesn;t work when the parent form is resized. To clarify again. I want the listview anchored to the tab so that it resizes along with the tab properly, when the main window is resiuzed, not outside the bounds of the tab. The autosize also doesn't resolve the issue of the button being positioned incorrectly.

Comment: My post wasn't clear -- I had to run to a meeting.  The reason your listview is WAY outside the bounds of the tab control is because it's statically sized WAY wider than you even allocate to the form.  Delete the .Size definition on the ListView2 item altogether and use the autosize code I provided.  When I do that (delete .Size and use .AutoSize), the listview2 scales to the tab2 with the growth and shrinking of the mainform.

Comment: Eh? Firstly how is $DSList.Size = '510,150' outside the bounds of a form that is $form.MinimumSize = '585,700'? Your edit as explained doesn't work for me at all. Can you post working code where the listview resizes along with the tab when the main form is resized? It also ignores the repositioning of the button when the form is dragged also as that needs to be anchored.

Comment: Posted.  I don't know what you want to do with your button.  If you're not anchoring the listview to the bottom then if the button is below and to the left, should it need to dynamically adjust?  and if so, in what way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is not working has to do with the order you add controls to the control collection. You are adding your *ListView* and *Button* before adding the *TabPage*. The *ListView* then does not have any information on the width of the *TabPage*. The *Anchor* Parameter will then cause trouble since it is based on local coordinates within the *TabPage*.

You either add each control object right after the parameters are set:

```
$MainTab.Controls.Add($TabPage1)
```

Or if you want to keep your array and add them at once you'll have to move your `$TabPage2` Parameters right after the `$TabPage1` Parameters and then add them both together right away before any other controls:

```
$MainTab.Controls.AddRange(@($TabPage1,$TabPage2))
```

Additionally your *TabControl* needs the local coordinates reset to the top-left corner of the Tab or else the the *Anchor* will position your objects on the invisible position grid.

This is why you had the following problem:

> TabPage1 controls now reposition/resize but I had to use some
> really funky location and size values:

Add the following Parameter to `$MainTab` to fix this:

```
$MainTab.AutoSize = $true
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I'm working with:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
#
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.MinimumSize = '585,700'
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$form.MaximizeBox = $false
$form.CancelButton = $ExitButton
#Autoscaling settings
$form.AutoScale = $true
$form.AutoScaleMode = "Font"
$ASsize = New-Object System.Drawing.SizeF(7,15)
$form.AutoScaleDimensions = $ASsize
#
#
$MainTab = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabControl
$MainTab.Size = '540,465'
$MainTab.Location = '15,95'
$MainTab.Multiline = $True
$MainTab.Name = 'TabPage'
$MainTab.SelectedIndex = 0
$MainTab.Anchor = 'Top,Left,Bottom,Right'
#
$TabPage1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
$Tabpage1.Name = 'TabPage1'
$Tabpage1.Padding = '5,5,5,5'
$Tabpage1.TabIndex = 1
$Tabpage1.Text = 'Host SSH'
$Tabpage1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$TabPage1.Enabled = $false
#
$ESXhostList = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
$ESXhostList.View = [System.Windows.Forms.View]::Details
$ESXhostList.Location = '10,15'
$ESXhostList.Size = '510,150'
$ESXhostList.Columns.Add('Host Name',420) | Out-Null
$ESXhostList.Columns.Add('SSH Status',80) | Out-Null
$ESXhostList.Anchor = 'Top,Left,Right'
#
$ConnectBtn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ConnectBtn.Location = '20,190'
$ConnectBtn.Size = '54,24'
$ConnectBtn.Text = 'Connect'
$ConnectBtn.BackgroundImageLayout = 'Center'
$ConnectBtn.Enabled = $true
$ConnectBtn.Anchor = 'Left,Bottom'
#
$TabPage1.Controls.AddRange(@($ESXhostList,$ConnectBtn))
################################################################################
# TabPage 2
################################################################################
$TabPage2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
$Tabpage2.Name = 'TabPage2'
$Tabpage2.Padding = '5,5,5,5'
$Tabpage2.TabIndex = 2
$Tabpage2.Text = 'Datastores'
$Tabpage2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$TabPage2.Enabled = $false
#
$DSList = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
$DSList.View = [System.Windows.Forms.View]::Details
$DSList.Location ='10,15'
$DSList.AutoSize = [System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode]::GrowAndShrink
$DSList.Columns.Add('Name',160) | Out-Null
$DSList.Columns.Add('FreeGB',65) | Out-Null
$DSList.Anchor = 'Top,Left,Right'
#
$ConnectBtn2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ConnectBtn2.Location = '10, 120'
$ConnectBtn2.Size = '54,24'
$ConnectBtn2.Text = 'Connect'
#$ConnectBtn2.BackgroundImageLayout = 'Center'
$ConnectBtn2.Enabled = $true
#$ConnectBtn2.Anchor = 'Left,Bottom'
#
$TabPage2.Controls.AddRange(@($DSList,$ConnectBtn2))
#
#
$MainTab.Controls.AddRange(@($TabPage1,$TabPage2))
#
# Info/Logging Window
$ProgressLog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$ProgressLog.Location = '15,570'
$ProgressLog.Size = '540,80'
$ProgressLog.Multiline = $true
$ProgressLog.Anchor = 'Left,Bottom,Right'
$ProgressLog.TabStop = $false
$ProgressLog.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
$ProgressLog.ReadOnly = $true
#
# Add all the Form controls
$form.Controls.AddRange(@($MainTab,$ProgressLog))
#
#End
# Show form
$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$form.Dispose()
```

Trying to find the blog article I used for an AD tree searcher form I created where it explained very well the alignment, docking, and autofilling issues in Winforms.  Will add if I can.

Comment: Thank you for posting the code, but yes, you misunderstand my intent. I want to anchor the listview to the bottom as well so that it expands downward with the form resize (as it would do normally with anchoring to top/left/bottom/right with a fixed start size) therefore I need to anchor the button to "bottom" to move it proportionally - there are also other control on the tab which will need anchoring (I simplified the form to post it here).
Sorry for any misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to get the desired result like this purely by trial and error. TabPage1 controls now reposition/resize bnut I had to use some really funky location and size values:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms -ErrorAction Stop

#
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.MinimumSize = '585,700'
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$form.MaximizeBox = $false
$form.CancelButton = $ExitButton
#Autoscaling settings
$form.AutoScale = $true
$form.AutoScaleMode = "Font"
$ASsize = New-Object System.Drawing.SizeF(7,15)
$form.AutoScaleDimensions = $ASsize
#
# Parent Tab Control
$MainTab = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabControl
$MainTab.Size = '540,465'
$MainTab.Location = '15,15'
$MainTab.Name = 'TabPage'
$MainTab.SizeMode = 'FillToRight'
$MainTab.Anchor = 'Top,Left,Bottom,Right'

################################################################################
# TabPage 1
################################################################################
$TabPage1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
$Tabpage1.Padding = '5,5,5,5'
$Tabpage1.Text = 'Host SSH'
$TabPage1.Parent
#
$ESXhostList = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
$ESXhostList.View = [System.Windows.Forms.View]::Details
$ESXhostList.Location = '10,15'
$ESXhostList.Size = '180,-50'
$ESXhostList.Columns.Add('Host Name',420) | Out-Null
$ESXhostList.Columns.Add('SSH Status',80) | Out-Null
$ESXhostList.Anchor = 'Top,Left,Bottom,Right'

#
$ConnectBtn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ConnectBtn.Location = '10,-20'
$ConnectBtn.Size = '54,24'
$ConnectBtn.Text = 'Connect'
$ConnectBtn.Anchor = 'Left,Bottom'
#
$TabPage1.Controls.AddRange(@($ESXhostList,$ConnectBtn))
################################################################################
# TabPage 2
################################################################################
$TabPage2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
$Tabpage2.Padding = '5,5,5,5'
$Tabpage2.Text = 'Datastores'
#
$DSList = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
$DSList.View = [System.Windows.Forms.View]::Details
$DSList.Location ='10,15'
$DSList.Size = '510,150'
$DSList.Columns.Add('Name',160) | Out-Null
$DSList.Columns.Add('FreeGB',80) | Out-Null
# $DSList.Anchor = 'Top,Left,Right'

#
$ConnectBtn2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ConnectBtn2.Location = '20,190'
$ConnectBtn2.Size = '54,24'
$ConnectBtn2.Text = 'Connect'
#
$TabPage2.Controls.AddRange(@($DSList,$ConnectBtn2))
#
$MainTab.Controls.AddRange(@($TabPage1,$TabPage2))
#
# Info/Logging Window
$ProgressLog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$ProgressLog.Location = '15,570'
$ProgressLog.Size = '540,80'
$ProgressLog.Multiline = $true
$ProgressLog.Anchor = 'Left,Bottom,Right'
$ProgressLog.TabStop = $false
$ProgressLog.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
$ProgressLog.ReadOnly = $true
#
# Add all the Form controls
$form.Controls.AddRange(@($MainTab,$ProgressLog))
#
#
#End
# Show form
$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$form.Dispose()
```

But can anyone explain why it works like this and what's happening?

Comment: The *TabPage* has local coordinates. Setting the *Anchor* Parameter will move the x0,y0 location around on the (invisible) 9Tile anchor grid. If you set the `Anchor = 'Bottom, Right'` the x0,y0 will be on the top-left corner of the bottom right tile. That's why you had to use `-` values to move things back. You'll need to set `AutoSize = $True` in your initial *TabControl* to reset the coordinates to always be the top-left corner of your *TabPage*.

Answer (score 0):

It's an older question but I managed to figure it out.
You only have to explicitly set the Size of the TabPage itself and nothing more.
For the default windows drawing style, the Size paramater is as follows: System.Drawing.Size(WidthOfParentTabControl - 8, HeightOfParentTabControl - 28)

Tested under PS 5.1

**Edit**: added some more Controls to demonstrate it better

Here is the full code, just save it and run:

```
using namespace System.Windows.Forms
using namespace System.Drawing
using namespace System.Collections.Generic

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

#region Initialize Components
    #Mainwindow
    $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $Form.ClientSize = New-Object Point(1280,720)
    $Form.text = "Resolution"
    $Form.TopMost = $false

    #region MainTabControl
    [TabControl] $tabControl = New-Object TabControl
    $tabControl.Location = New-Object Point(12, 12)
    #Size(1248, 668) so I have a 12-12-12-12 "margin" on the tabcontrol
    $tabControl.Size = New-Object Size(1256, 696)
    $tabControl.Anchor = "top,right,bottom,left"
    #endregion

    #region Sample Tab
    [TabPage] $tabSample = New-Object TabPage
    $tabSample.Text = "Sample Tab"
    $tabSample.TabIndex = 0
    #Size(WParent - 8, HParent - 28)
    $tabSample.Size = New-Object Size(1248, 668)

        #region Controls
        [ListBox] $lbSample = New-Object ListBox
        [Button] $bSample = New-Object Button
        [Label] $lSample = New-Object Label

        $lbSample.Anchor = "left,bottom"
        $lbSample.Size = New-Object Size(800, 600)
        $lbSample.Location = New-Object Point(12, 50)

        $bSample.Anchor = "top,left,bottom,right"
        $bSample.Location = New-Object Point(12, 12)
        $bSample.Size = New-Object Size("80, 30")
        $bSample.Text = "Resizing button"

        $lSample.Text = "Anchor (right,bottom)"
        $lSample.Anchor = "right,bottom"
        $lSample.Location = New-Object Point(1150, 630)
        #endregion

    $tabSample.Controls.Add($lbSample)
    $tabSample.Controls.Add($bSample)
    $tabSample.Controls.Add($lSample)
    #endregion

    #Adding tabs to MainTabControl
    $tabControl.Controls.Add($tabSample)

    $tabControl.SelectedIndex = 0;
    $Form.Controls.Add($tabControl)
#endregion

[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```